# HTML Canvas scale

Tags: html, canvas, scale

I've started experimenting with drawing on a Canvas object. In the past my exposure to a Canvas has been centered (NPI) around image manipulation, so I'm moderately familiar with its coordinate system and transformation process. I'm working with a test canvas that has a screen dimension of 30 X 30. After getting a handle to the 2D context I issue one call:

```js
ctx.fillRect(0,0,10,10);
```

produces a little black spec about the size of a pin head in the upper left corner. To get the rectangle to be of any size, say something approximate 1/4 of the canvas, requires an adjustment to:

```js
ctx.fillRect(0,0,200,200);
```

So, how has this canvas's scale been skewed? Yes, I guess I could "de-scale" it back to something resembling normal, but I'd like to figure out what's causing this in the first place. I've disabled Jquery thinking it might be interfering somehow, but that did not help.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**:

The canvas is added to the dom along these lines:

```html
<canvas id='foo_" + self.groupIndex + "' class='hCanvasClassName'>"
```

whereby the CSS defines the width at 100% and the height is assigned by JS code.

Comment: Have you defined the size of the canvas on the canvas element or by css?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't show the code for this, but it sounds as you have applied the size for the canvas using CSS and not directly on the element which would explain why it scales down.

You need to do this:

```
<canvas width="30" height="30" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

If you did this:

```
<canvas style="width:30px;height;30px;" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

what will happen is that the canvas element uses a default size (300x150, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/CfMNf/) and then you scale that down to 30x30 by css which means everything now drawn to the canvas will be scaled accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I had looked for a default Canvas scale, but somehow missed a default canvas size. In answer to your question, I've update the original post. The Height was set as you suggestion, but the width was set via CSS to 100% - which is now manually calculated - and things work as one would expect. Thanks for your help. Regards.

Comment: I know this answer is three years old at this point, and I found this answer very useful, as a similar issue was driving me crazy.  But.. can anyone explain, or point me to an explanation, of the logic behind doing it this way?  And is there some way to change the canvas size, other than attributes on the element, without having to separately alter the scale?